# Different output for blank input in search function

Tags: javascript

I've written a small function for a search bar. Currently if the input doesn't match anything in my array, the function returns the last object in said array (which i made to be empty). I want to change it so that if the input is blank, the function returns "No Result" or something like that. Any ideas why this code isn't working as intended?

```js
let websitePages =
  '{"website_pages":[' +
  '{"name":"Hamza", "path":"/hamza/"},' +
  '{"name":"Jakub", "path":"/jakub/"},' +
  '{"name":"Kevin", "path":"/kevin/"},' +
  '{"name":"Sreeja", "path":"/sreeja/"},' +
  '{"name":"Tristan", "path":"/tristan/"},' +
  '{"name":"Math", "path":"/math/"},' +
  '{"name":"History", "path":"/history/"},' +
  '{"name":"Science", "path":"/sci/"},' +
  '{"name":"Literature", "path":"/lit/"},' +
  '{"name":"Periodic Table", "path":"/periodictable/"},' +
  '{"name":"API Collection", "path":"/api_collection/"},' +
  '{"name":"CRUD", "path":"/crud/"},' +
  '{"name":"Async CRUD", "path":"/crud_api/"},' +
  '{"name":"Database Search", "path":"/crud/search/"},' +
  '{"name":"Search (Database)", "path":"/crud/search/"},' +
  '{"name":"", "path":"//"}]}'; // this object is empty in case the user inputs a blank, so that the previous result is removed and no link is returned

function SearchMain() {
  list = JSON.parse(websitePages);
  input = document.getElementById("SearchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); // the user's input is changed to uppercase so that the search is not case-sensitive
  for (i = 0; i < websitePages.length; i++) {
    // this section goes through the items in my array and checks if the user's input is the same as any object name
    if (
      filter ===
      list.website_pages[i].name.toUpperCase().substring(0, filter.length)
    ) {
      //using substrings allows users to only input part of the page name instead of the whole thing
      link = list.website_pages[i].path;
      document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML =
        list.website_pages[i].name;
      document.getElementById("searchResult").href = link;
    } else if (filter === null) {
      document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = "No Results";
      document.getElementById("searchResult").href = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to create JSON. Create an object and then use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Use `if (filter == '')` and make it do what you want for blank input.

Answer (score 0):

For loop condition should be `i < list.website_pages.length`, also you should handle two error scenarios. One is input is empty and the search didnot find any valid match. I have updated them in the below fiddle.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let websitePages = '{"website_pages":[' +
  '{"name":"Hamza", "path":"/hamza/"},' +
  '{"name":"Jakub", "path":"/jakub/"},' +
  '{"name":"Kevin", "path":"/kevin/"},' +
  '{"name":"Sreeja", "path":"/sreeja/"},' +
  '{"name":"Tristan", "path":"/tristan/"},' +
  '{"name":"Math", "path":"/math/"},' +
  '{"name":"History", "path":"/history/"},' +
  '{"name":"Science", "path":"/sci/"},' +
  '{"name":"Literature", "path":"/lit/"},' +
  '{"name":"Periodic Table", "path":"/periodictable/"},' +
  '{"name":"API Collection", "path":"/api_collection/"},' +
  '{"name":"CRUD", "path":"/crud/"},' +
  '{"name":"Async CRUD", "path":"/crud_api/"},' +
  '{"name":"Database Search", "path":"/crud/search/"},' +
  '{"name":"Search (Database)", "path":"/crud/search/"},' +
  '{"name":"", "path":"//"}]}'; // this object is empty in case the user inputs a blank, so that the previous result is removed and no link is returned

function SearchMain() {
  list = JSON.parse(websitePages);
  input = document.getElementById('SearchInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); // the user's input is changed to uppercase so that the search is not case-sensitive
  let isFound = false;
  for (i = 0; i < list.website_pages.length; i++) { // this section goes through the items in my array and checks if the user's input is the same as any object name
    if (filter === list.website_pages[i].name.toUpperCase().substring(0, filter.length)) { //using substrings allows users to only input part of the page name instead of the whole thing
      link = list.website_pages[i].path;
      document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = list.website_pages[i].name;
      document.getElementById('searchResult').href = link;
      isFound = true;
    }
  }
  if (!filter || !isFound) {
    document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = "No Results"
    document.getElementById('searchResult').href = ""
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="SearchInput" />
<button onclick="SearchMain()">SearchMain</button>
<a id="searchResult"></a>
```

**Simplified solution.**

Avoid using for loop and make use of `Array.find` to find the matching node from the list.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let websitePages = '{"website_pages":[' +
  '{"name":"Hamza", "path":"/hamza/"},' +
  '{"name":"Jakub", "path":"/jakub/"},' +
  '{"name":"Kevin", "path":"/kevin/"},' +
  '{"name":"Sreeja", "path":"/sreeja/"},' +
  '{"name":"Tristan", "path":"/tristan/"},' +
  '{"name":"Math", "path":"/math/"},' +
  '{"name":"History", "path":"/history/"},' +
  '{"name":"Science", "path":"/sci/"},' +
  '{"name":"Literature", "path":"/lit/"},' +
  '{"name":"Periodic Table", "path":"/periodictable/"},' +
  '{"name":"API Collection", "path":"/api_collection/"},' +
  '{"name":"CRUD", "path":"/crud/"},' +
  '{"name":"Async CRUD", "path":"/crud_api/"},' +
  '{"name":"Database Search", "path":"/crud/search/"},' +
  '{"name":"Search (Database)", "path":"/crud/search/"},' +
  '{"name":"", "path":"//"}]}'; // this object is empty in case the user inputs a blank, so that the previous result is removed and no link is returned

function SearchMain() {
  list = JSON.parse(websitePages);
  input = document.getElementById('SearchInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); // the user's input is changed to uppercase so that the search is not case-sensitive
  const matchingNode = filter ? list.website_pages.find(node => filter === node.name.toUpperCase().substring(0, filter.length)) : null;
  if (matchingNode) {
    document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = matchingNode.name;
    document.getElementById('searchResult').href = matchingNode.path;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = "No Results"
    document.getElementById('searchResult').href = ""
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="SearchInput" />
<button onclick="SearchMain()">SearchMain</button>
<a id="searchResult"></a>
```